# How do I create a lazy property without getting errors?

Tags: ios, swift, properties, lazy-initialization

Trying to get the hang of creating `lazy` `class` properties. Sometimes it works, other times I get errors and I'm not sure I understand when it's okey to do it and when its not. For example, I created this:

```
lazy var backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    return self.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
}()
```

Works wonders with no errors. Then I tried one that fetches `core data`:

```
lazy var fetchCoreData: [LocalDoorCoreDataObject] = { return coreDataHandler.fetchAll(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<LocalDoorCoreDataObject>(entityName: "LocalDoorCoreDataObject") }()
```

As far as I can see I use the exact same format, but I still get an error

> Expected , seperator

and

> Expected expression in list expressions

I gues there is some reason I'm not allowed to do it with the `core data`property, but I'm not sure what. What am I missing?

Comment: Du har glömt en slutparantes - you’re missing an end parenthesis

Comment: Haha, my bad! Thanks alot for noticing Sajjon :D

Comment: And I don't see the point in using lazy here either, you want to perform the fetch every time otherwise you will miss any changes done (new, update, delete). And if your goal is to only fetch once then declare a ordinary array variable and load it in viewDidLoad or similar

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. I fixed by removing lazy, = and ()